# React Native - ScrollView - onStartShouldSetResponder not working?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a global wrapper for my app that handles clicks to automatically dismiss the keyboard when it's open. However, this leads to the ScrollView not working since it is wrapped inside of a Pressable.

```
const MyApp = () => (
  <Pressable onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <ScrollView>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  </Pressable>
)
```

I expected to be able to fix this by adding the `onStartShouldSetResponder` prop to the ScrollView:

```
const MyApp = () => (
  <Pressable onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <ScrollView onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
      <Text>Example text</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  </Pressable>
)
```

However, this didn't work as expected and I had to use the following code to make it work:

```
const MyApp = () => (
  <Pressable onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <ScrollView>
      <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
        <Text>Example text</Text>
        <Text>Example text</Text>
        <Text>Example text</Text>
        <Text>Example text</Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </Pressable>
)
```

This requires creating a custom style prop for the View that wraps the content of ScrollView. I'm not sure why my expected solution didn't work and what I am misunderstanding about the `onStartShouldSetResponder` prop on the ScrollView. What is the technical reason why my expected solution doesn't work?